# C# WinForms DateTimePicker Custom Format

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, date-format

I have a `DateTimePicker` on my form. I'd like part of the format to include "today", "tomorrow" etc as appropriate. I've got a simple implementation to work out the value (and there are much better ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time)) but I'd like to take that implementation and put the value directly into the `CustomFormat` property of the `DateTimePicker`.

For example, given the following format:

```
dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd MMM yyyy (YTT) HH:mm";
```

To produce the following display at runtime on 16th April 2011 at 12:00:

```
"16 Apr 2011 (today) 12:00"
```

I expect this is something involving building a `IFormatProvider`/`ICustomFormatter` implementation and <strike>hacking</strike> customising the `CurrentCulture` to use it.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use `'` around the static text in a custom date format string.

```
 string ytt = "today"; //Simple example... Update to determine yesterday, today or tomorrow.

 this.dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd MMM yyyy '(" + ytt + ")' HH:mm";
```