# Parse a string to a date without slashes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime, formatting

In C# / Winform, I'm able to parse a string to a date if the user input: `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
DateTime.Parse(date).ToString();
```

I would like to be able to parse without the slash (like in a datagridview or a DateTimePicker for example).

`01022012` should be parsed to `01/02/2012`

Anyone know how to parse it with `DateTime.Parse`?

Here is my code :

```
    private void dataGridView_BadgeService_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView_BadgeService.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "DateDebut" || dataGridView_BadgeService.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "DateFin")
        {
            string date = Convert.ToString(e.FormattedValue).Trim();

            if (date.Length > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    DateTime _date;
                    DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out _date);
                    date = _date.ToShortDateString();
                    dataGridView_BadgeService.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = date;
                }
                catch
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("Merci de saisir une date, ou laissez cette zone vierge", "Action-Informatique", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                   e.Cancel = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is the Exception Message :

[image]

It says that : "System.FormatException: The string is not recognized as a DateTime valide"

Comment: @Sander While i'm sure this question has been answered on Stackoverflow before, i cannot find any with a quick search. And that [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793163/c-sharp-winforms-datetimepicker-custom-format) would in no way help Walter.

Comment: Why is your question tagged json, how is json is invloved? If you are trying to parse out a json response there are MUCH easier ways to do it then parsing our each part by hand.

Answer (score 17):

Try with something like this...

```
string unslashedValue = "01022012"
DateTime date;
DateTime.TryParseExact(unslashedValue, "ddMMyyyy", 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, date);
```

... and, with `date` variable, you only need to...

```
string slashedValue = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Suggestion to the OP: use the `TryParseExact` method to avoid the `FormatException`

Comment: Nice! Updated with your suggestion!

Comment: I tried your tips and the forma is OK ! But, i don't know why, i have a FormatException on my DataGrid. In fact, i use this code in order to check if the data inputted is a date. I edited my code. Have you some ideas please ? Thanks

Comment: What is the exact message of this `FormatException`? It helps us to figure out what are you doing...

Comment: "System.FormatException : The string is not recognized as a dateTime valide" (It's a DataGridView Exception). I edited my post with the screenshot.

Comment: It's possible that is related to a problem with the order of day and month in your date string. Please, try to set the values: `"01012013"` and `"01312013"`. Are you reproducing the problem?

Comment: Yes i'm reproducing the problem. It appear to be related to the DatagriView. Is there a way to tell that a cell is a DateTime, in order to having the auto-formatting ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32502/discussion-between-huorswords-and-walter-fabio-simoni)

Answer (score 3):

HuorSwords isn't *wrong* (other than the use of `string` as the input value), but the answer doesn't strictly answer the question: in order to *display* the date as requested, you need to format to a string after the fact:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, 
  "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string formattedDate = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: It's true... use of a protected keyword as variable... unforgivable! Updated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like an awful lot of work when you could do something as simple as the two examples below. **Date and time can be formatted using predefined formats and also user-defined formats.**
This is a link to a brief video demonstrating both uses from a text editing program I'm designing.
https://od.lk/s/MTRfMjY2NzQxODVf/2022-03-20-20-55-52.mp4

**This link will certainly get you on the right track:**
https://www.vbtutor.net/vb2008/vb2008_lesson16.html

```
'Declaration (If you wish to use SpeechSynthesizer)
Private Ethro As SpeechSynthesizer = New SpeechSynthesizer()

Ethro.SpeakAsync(Format(Now, "Long Date"))

'Or a simple MsgBox:
        MsgBox(Format(Now, "Long Date"))
```